# solve system equation: $ 2a^2 - 1 = b, 2b^2 - 1 = c, 2c^2 - 1 = a $

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I have this system equation:

$$ 2a^2 - 1 = b $$ 
$$ 2b^2 - 1 = c $$
$$ 2c^2 - 1 = a $$

From system equation we see that $ a \neq 0 , b \neq 0, c \neq 0 $ , so :
$ 2a^2 - 1 \neq 0 => a \neq \sqrt{\frac 1 2} $ . 
Also we can write: $ b \neq \sqrt{\frac 1 2} $ And $ c \neq \sqrt{\frac 1 2} $

But I don't know if this is the answer or I need to find exact numbers that satisfy this system (btw, I found an answer and that's : $a = 1, b = 1, c = 1 $).

Comment: @Adriano, It is an 8th degree polynomial, so there are at most 8 solutions for $a$. Your graph shows 8 intersections, I don't know why it only lists 5.

Comment: $2x^2 - 1 = \cos(2\cos^{-1}(x))$

Comment: By graphing, it seems there are 8 solutions to the equation $2(2(2a^2-1)^2-1)^2-1=a$. Both $a=1$ and $a=-1/2$ work.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need the way of solution not just solutions itself.

Comment: $2(2(2a^2−1)^2−1)^2−1-a=(a-1)(2a+1)(8a^3-6a+1)*(8a^3+4a^2-4a-1)$

Comment: If $a = \cos x$, then $b = 2a^2-1 = \cos(2x)$, $c = 2b^2-1 = \cos(4x)$, $a = 2c^2-1 = \cos(8x)$. You can find the 8 solutions for $a$ by solving the equation $\cos(8x) = \cos(x)$.

Comment: You haven't specified what kind of roots you are looking for: integer, rational, real or complex? The trigonometric approach above will not easily give you the complex roots.

Comment: @AlexM. By the fundamental theorem of algebra, a polynomial of degree 8 has exatly 8 solutions in the complex numbers. You can see that the equation $\cos(8x)=\cos(x)$ gives exatly 8 different values for $\cos(x)$ and hence all the solutions are real numbers.

Answer (score -1):

The given system of equations is symmetric, which means that by substituting the variables in the equations by any permutation of the set $\left (a,b,c \right )$ we get the same system all over again. Using that fact, equality $a=b=c$ must hold.

Now simply by using $a=b$ from the first equation of the system we obtain:
$$2a^2-a-1=0$$ Using quadratic formula we get $a_{1}=1$ and $a_{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore, the solution of the system is:

$$\left ( a,b,c \right )=\left \{ \left ( 1,1,1 \right ), \left ( -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2} \right)  \right \}$$